# How to get IP of server that initiated redirect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, http, http-headers

I hope you could help me with the following question:

A user clicks a hyperlink in a page. Server A handles the request and redirects the client to a URL on Server B (more specifically I am using the Response.Redirect method in .NET on server A).

I have been asked to restrict access to Server B to redirects originating from Server A only (by blocking  IP's other than Server A's). At first I thought this could be achieved by using the HTTP 'referer' header, however, it seems it is up to the browser to set this to a URL (rather than IP), and it is not guaranteed to do so.

I guess there is no way to set the HTTP 'referer' on server A in .NET (to server A's IP)? (my intuition is that would be a security hole). So my question is, how can I restrict access to Server B to redirects originating from Server A?

Any help much appreciated,

Martijn

Comment: You're talking about both redirecting, and blocking IP addresses. Which is it?

Comment: @Greg. Thanks. I've clarified the question in the last paragraph.

Comment: I'm still not sure how blocking IP addresses is related to redirecting.

Comment: @Greg. I want to block the IP of any server other than Server A. Server A is the server that initiates the redirect, so it is not as straightforward as just blocking the IP of the client following the redirect. Any suggestions how to rephrase my questions are welcome. I feel I am a bit of a dummy on the topic so apologies if my question is not as clear as it could be :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do it that way, browsers only set the referrer in certain conditions and a client can spoof this.

The referrer header is a request header - not a response header, so Server A cannot set this.

You would have to do something server side (a token perhaps) so long as you are in control of both servers, then pass the token as a parameter in the URL you redirect to.

Answer (score 2):

you could send a signed message in the redirect process, so that server B can verify that it was signed by server A

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you how I understood your question:
You have a set of web pages(p1,p2,p3,p4) distributed on two servers A(p1,p2) and B(p3,p4).
clients can click links to pages p1,p2 that redirect the user to pages p3,p4 through server A to server B.

you want users be restricted so that they cannot access pages p3,p4. In other words get server B restrict access to pages p3,p4 except through redirects generated by server A.

If I got the point this way you can let server A appends a query string to the url while redirect and let server B check that query string and instead of using Response.Redirect from server A you can use Server.Transfer in order to hide the url from the user.